# Convert array of vectors to DenseVector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running Spark 2.1 with Scala. I am trying to convert and array of vectors into a `DenseVector`.

Here is my dataframe:

```
scala> df_transformed.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- vals: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- hashValues: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: vector (containsNull = true)

scala> df_transformed.show()
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|          id|                vals|          hashValues|
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|401310732094|[-0.37154,-0.1159...|[[-949518.0], [47...|
|292125586474|[-0.30407,0.35437...|[[-764013.0], [31...|
|362051108485|[-0.36748,0.05738...|[[-688834.0], [18...|
|222480119030|[-0.2509,0.55574,...|[[-1167047.0], [2...|
|182270925238|[0.32288,-0.60789...|[[-836660.0], [97...|
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

For example, I need to extract the value of the `hashValues` column into a `DenseVector`for id 401310732094.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with an `UDF`:

```
import spark.implicits._
val convertToVec = udf((array: Seq[Vector]) => 
  Vectors.dense(array.flatMap(_.toArray).toArray)
)

val df = df_transformed.withColumn("hashValues", convertToVec($"hashValues"))
```

This will overwrite the `hashValues` column with a new one containing a `DenseVector`.

Tested with a dataframe with following schema:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- hashValues: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: vector (containsNull = true)
```

The result is:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- hashValues: vector (nullable = true)
```